# linking libtiff - LNK2001: unresolve external symbol TIFFOpen

Tags: visual-studio-2010, libtiff, lnk2001

I am using MSVS 2010 on a 64 bit machine. I installed tiff libraries version 3.8.2 using the set-up file, changed project properties sheet: include - *\GnuWin32\include; linker - *\GnuWin32\lib, input - libtiff.lib. But MSVS 2010 still gives me the linker errors:

LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFOpen
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFGetField
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TIFFIsTiled

(because of the function calls in one of my source files).

I have tried adding the include directory to my environment variables Path as well, to no avail. 
I also downloaded tiff-4.0.3.zip and built libraries from command prompt as described on the libtiff website. I updated project properties sheet accordingly: include - *\libtiff; linker - *\libtiff, input - libtiff.lib, libtiff_i.lib. I even copied libtiff.dll to *\Windows\system and *\Windows\system32 directories and also added the *\libtiff directory to my environment variables Path. But still, MSVS 2010 gives me the same errors.

I have searched online and no one seems to have had such a problem, or for those who have had similar issues with different libraries, the solutions are what I have tried to do above. I have spent almost two days on this now, and am desperate for a solution. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Yipeee!!! I solved it. Since I am a newbie to MSVS, I didn't know it had its own command prompt. I was using the normal cmd from windows, but I used Visual Studio x64 Command Prompt and it finally compiled. 
It pays not to give up ha - thanks to switching to bing search where I got a result that gave me that idea. This tailored google search... :-/